# How do I get the default views for a ListView Section Headers and items?

Tags: java, android

I want to replicate the list look of the sidebar/action bar dropdown in Gmail--namely, the nice all-cap section headers and items with the faded number on the right. I know I need to create my own SpinnerAdapter, which I've started. Where I'm stuck is how to get these standard views and put the desired text in the right sub-views (with I guess `view.findViewById`). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    Object item = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
              (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (item instanceof String) {
        String headerText = (String) item;
        // TODO: inflate the ICS section header view,
        // populate with headerText, and return
    } else {
        ListItem listItem = (ListItem) item;
        // TODO: inflate the ICS text/number view, populate with
        // listItem.getText()/getNumber() and return            
    }
}
```

Here's a visual reference of what I'm talking about: [ICS Gmail App on Transformer Prime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcxic.png)